# hp envy m6 ubuntu 15.04

Tags: xubuntu

hello i wanted to knoaw if my hp envy m6 can install ubuntu 15.05 on it? i had a dell laptop from school that was able to but i just like my personal leptop to use for it. it has the beats audio speakers and a amd a10-4600 just wanted to find a toutorial around the boot options. i have already changed my bios to legacy boot and made my bootable usb the first boot option. i just cant get my coomputer to get it to boot off my usb(note: this is the same bootable device i used before on the school computer)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by ...can't get it to boot from USB? Why not? What does it do instead?

Comment: well i dont know if theres a shortcut key in the bios to pull up what i want to boot from. when i turn it on after setting the legacy boot order it will just run to windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP BIOS should let you pick boot device by hitting F9 as soon as you see the HP logo.  If it's not F9, start trying Del/Esc/F1/F2/...

Test that everything works before you go and install on it.

Comment: thanks f9 worked and everything but the vbeats adio is working perfectly!